# I need help in Filter some data id Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a model structure, but have tough time understanding how to use the Django filters.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)

class Bar(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Tables(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(to=Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to be able to filter the user of a table from the model below.

Comment: So you are given a `Table` and you want to retrieve the `User` it points to?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the `User` for which *`mytable`* refers to a `Bar` that refers to that `User` with:

```
User.objects.get(bar__tables=mytable)
```

Since this is a `ForeignKey` and a `OneToOneField`, we know for sure that there is only one such `User`.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `user`, instead of <s>`user_id`</s>.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Table` instead of <s>`Tables`</s>.

Comment: How am i then able to get the name of the current user's bar

Comment: @coderboy: your bar has no name? if it has you can access it with `myuser.bar.name`.

Comment: I just edited the question just now. I have added a name field for the bar